# How to change the value of "Run Thread Groups consecutively" check box from command-line to toggle between parallel and consecutive mode in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I would like to update the value of this check box "Run Thread Groups consecutively" while executing JMeter in non-GUI mode from the command line. The purpose is to switch between parallel and consecutive mode as per requirement. Although I have searched the documentation, I couldn't find any information on how to pass this Boolean value as a command-line parameter.

[image]

Is there a way to modify this specific parameter from the command line while running JMeter in non-GUI mode?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think it's possible, at least not with [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5)

There is an [open enhancement request for this](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/issues/4468)

The options are in:

1. JMeter [.jmx file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) is basically an XML file so you can change the value using [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) editor or equivalent
2. You can use [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool for [running your existing JMeter test](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Run-Existing-JMX-File), Taurus allows [modification of JMeter scripts](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts) so you could do something like:

   ```
   execution:
     iterations: -1
     concurrency: 100
     scenario:
       script: your-test.jmx
       modifications:
         set-prop:
           "Test Plan>TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups": true
   ```